# If it is a top level category show children otherwise show sibling categories

Tags: categories, theme-development, customization

I found a great [piece of code](http://www.kablooeystudios.com/woocommerce-sidebar-parents-or-children/) for my category.php file to list categories for a specific taxonomy (not tested). BUT - how can I change the code (or achieve it) to show the default Wordpress categories like:

If the current category is a top level category (myewebsite.com/category/toplevel), list ONLY the children categories:

```
Child 1
Child 2
Child 3
```

But if the current category is not a top level category (myewebsite.com/category/toplevel/parent), it should show ONLY its sibling categories:

```
Sibling 1
Sibling 2
Sibling 3
```

Here is the code i found:

```
    <?php
$term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$termid = get_term($term, 'product_cat' );
if($termid->parent > 0)
{
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => false,
'child_of' => $termid->parent,
);
$siblingproducts = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);
foreach ($siblingproducts as $siblingproduct) {
if ($siblingproduct->term_id == $term ) { ?>
<li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li>
<?php } ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $siblingproduct ); ?>"><?php echo $siblingproduct->name; ?><?php echo "<span class='count'>" . $siblingproduct->count . "</span>"; ?></a></li>
<?php }
} else {
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => false,
'child_of' => $term
);
$subproducts = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);
foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct) { ?>
<li> <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $subproduct ); ?>"><?php echo $subproduct->name; ?><?php echo "<span class='count'>" . $subproduct->count . "</span>"; ?></a></li>
<?php }
}
?>
```

Any suggestions on how to change the code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simply change all instances of `product_cat` with `category`

Comment: Your suggestion do not work...?

Comment: What do you mean by do not work.

Comment: It lists all the categories one by one - regardles wich cat im on...

Comment: I cannot do any tests now. Do a `var_dump($variable_to_test);` and dump the result of every variable after the variable and check if the values returned are correct